# Using Ajax/JQuery to make a search form functional

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I have a form that I want to use to send data to a Python file. I am expecting it to return a string in xml format.

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('button').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://projfootball.web.engr.illinois.edu/410.py',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            //Show response on page
});
</script>
```

My question is what would I write in the success field in order to show the response on the webpage? Also, how would I be able to extract parts of it to show on the webpage? I'm sorry if  the question looks trivial but I have absolutely no experience using jQuery or AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following inside your success function where "selector" is the id, class or tag of your html element that you want to update:

```
$('selector').html(response);
```

Check this example to parse the XML (copied from jquery docs):

```
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>

<script>
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

// Change the title to "XML Title"
$title.text( "XML Title" );

// Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it depends what type of response you are getting. In addition of what Medhat Gayed suggested above, let's say you have your object inside a JSON object..

```
$('button').click( function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://projfootball.web.engr.illinois.edu/410.py',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        $('selector').html(response.Text);
    },
    error: function(response){
        $('selector').html(response.Text);
    }
);
```